# How to make Float Action Button at right of bottom of the page

Tags: android, xml

I just created a Float Action button and put the attributes aliign parent bottom and right but it doesn't shown I don't know what I did wrong exactly here's my xml code................................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_show_order"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="624dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:context="abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.PaymentActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#f0ff4800"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/showOrderListID"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPayment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/showOrderListID"
        android:text="Payment Type:" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/paymentSpinner"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
            android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/spinner_sla"
            android:layout_below="@+id/showOrderListID"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvPayment"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvPayment" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pay" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="624dp" remove and use match_parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this layout:

Remove height , width declaration and use `match_parent` attribute..and use `FrameLayout` as a Root layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_show_order"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#f0ff4800"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/showOrderListID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPayment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/showOrderListID"
            android:text="Payment Type:" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/paymentSpinner"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvPayment"
            android:layout_below="@+id/showOrderListID"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvPayment"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_border_help"
            android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/bottom_border_help" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fbLiveAccount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/scale_16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/scale_16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/scale_16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/color_f27f17" />
```

Comment: remove  android:layout_width="368dp"
              android:layout_height="624dp" and set as matchparent

Comment: Please provide some explanation to this answer